# while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) Loop is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I had debugged code but don't know why While statement is not executing . After putting NSlog I came to know it's mismatching the result. 101 and SQLITE_ROW is equal to 100.

But query has result. If I fetch Select * from table name its returning me result and while statement executes. If I fetch result

```
sql_stmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM DeviceType WHERE upper(TypeName) = upper('%@')", deviceType];
```

While statement never execute so please help. don't know where is the problem.

Here is the code:

```
NSArray* paths  =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ClientDB.sqlite"];

NSString* sql_stmt = [self searchStringForLocalData];

BOOL found = NO;

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char* sql1 =  [sql_stmt UTF8String]; 

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSNumber *typeCount;

    typeCount = 0;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql1, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@" %d, %d ",sqlite3_step(statement),SQLITE_ROW);

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)   {

            // The second parameter indicates the column index into the result set.
            int primaryKey1 = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);


    NSNumber *typeId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:primaryKey1];

NSString *typeName =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

            NSString* sql_stmt1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Devices WHERE DeviceTypeId =%d",primaryKey1];


            const char *sql1 =  [sql_stmt1 UTF8String];

            sqlite3_stmt *statement;

            NSNumber *typeCount;

            typeCount = 0;
```

Comment: So, what code is sqlite3_step returning, and what does sqlite3_errmsg report??

Comment: So, what code is sqlite3_step returning, and what does sqlite3_errmsg report??

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment, the code calls `sqlite3_step` once for the `NSLog`, and then a second time in the condition of the `while` loop.
If your query returns exactly one record, the first `sqlite3_step` call will step to that record, and the second `sqlite3_step` call will then report (correctly) that no further results are available.

Just remove that `NSLog` call.

Alternatively, call `sqlite3_step` only once, and use the same return value for both the logging and the loop:

```
int rc;
...
while (1) {
    rc = sqlite3_step(statement);
    NSLog(@" %d, %d ", rc, SQLITE_ROW);
    if (rc != SQLITE_ROW)
        break;
    ...
}
if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
    NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Comment: -1 because you do not log sqlite3_errmsg on an error.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the following syntax

```
while(sqlite3_step(stmt)!=SQLITE_DONE)
{
     //do ur processing
   for(i=0;i<NO_OF_COLS;i++)
   {
    char * tmp1=sqlite3_column_text(stmt,i);
        if(tmp1!=NULL)
        {
            //use the value
        }
        else
        {
            //use a default
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way already . It allows to enter inside while loop .but when code try to fetch result for first row it crashes the app and showing there is nothing inside the row

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: If a col in your table is null sqlite3 api returns a null pointer so try to add a check saying sqlite3_column_text(stmt,i)!=null

Comment: I changed this statement sql_stmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM DeviceType WHERE upper(TypeName) = upper('%@')", deviceType];

To

 sql_stmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DeviceType WHERE upper(TypeName) = upper('%@')", deviceType]

Now its printing NSLog (100,100)

But I'm wondering its matching now . But still its not going inside the Loop , Any idea

Comment: when you execute a count(*) query it returns the number of rows returned alone . There is no data so it will come out of the loop. It is the expected behaviour. Try that null check

Comment: Yeah its NULL. But when i execute this statement
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM DeviceType ORDER BY lower(TypeName)";

its returning me 7 result

Comment: You have 7 rows but the column values for a particular row might be NULL so check for that and replace with "" your application must work fine

Comment: Will you please suggest me where to check for "" or what statement i have to write to put this check ? thanks

Comment: use something along the lines of my edit to do your processing. also consider removing the NSLog statement because you already step through the first row there, you will get values only from the second row in the while loop

Comment: This code will blow up when `sqlite3_step` returns an error. In any case, it is no improvement over the code in the question.

Comment: @CL Well sqlite3_step returns an int and if theres an error sqlite3_prepare_v2 would not be returning SQLITE_OK. This is a convinience wrapper around deprecated methods like sqlite3_get_table() so it is safe to say sqlite3_step wont be called when there is an error

Comment: @user3182350 It is possible for `sqlite3_step` to fail even when `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds, e.g., when the database is locked, or when an I/O error happens. (And it is [sqlite3_get_table](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html) that is a convenience wrapper.)

Comment: The issue in the code is the null pointer exception due to missing col values . The check for SQLITE_BUSY and other result codes are valid I accept but they are not the cause of the error encountered :)

Answer (score -1):

It shows that your table is totally empty. You may want to check your insert whether it works correctly. If you're using `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to prepare your statement with some `?` marks, remember to execute your query after all. Simply like this:

```
if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) NSLog(@"INSERTED");
else NSLog(@"NO INSERTED");
```

Note: It will display error only if your query is wrong, but not your prepared statement was executed or not.